# Android Pass String Data Between Fragments

Tags: android-fragments

How to pass string data between fragments like we did in Activity using intents?Plea

Answer (score 7):

Use [`setArguments(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments%28android.os.Bundle%29) and [`getArguments(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments%28%29) if you are loading one fragment from another

Comment: can you please provide an example so that i don't have doubts with the syntax

Comment: Simply call `setArguments(aBundle)` on the Fragment that you are about to add/replace into a container where aBundle contains your string as a string extra data. Then in `onCreate` say in your Fragment simply call `getArguments` to retrieve the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Use interfaces demonstrated here
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity