# how to replace tabhost, actvitygroup and child activities with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabactivity, activitygroup

I have already implemented one application using TabActivity. Now, I want change from TabActvity to Fragments, but in my application I need to show 4 tabs and each tab I want to show multiple child activities, Previously I had created TabActivity and created 4 ActvityGroups and from each ActivityGroup I need to show multiple child Activities.Now, how can I achieve this scenario by using Fragments.

Please help...

Comment: maybe this link be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987334/separate-back-stack-for-each-tab-in-android-using-fragments

Comment: @GeorgyGobozov the above link shows what exactly I want. but in the above example how can pass intent values from one fragment to another fragment.

Comment: pass data between fragments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194548/how-to-pass-data-between-fragments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815555/android-pass-string-data-between-fragments

Comment: @GeorgyGobozov: Thank you for your reply, I can pass data from one fragment to another fragment by using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149802/how-to-transfer-some-data-to-another-fragment/7149906#7149906

Answer (score 0):

Check out [LINK](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/) which will show you the way of converting TabActivity into the FragmentActivity.

I hope it will help you.

Thanks.